# how to check if all JSON values are of type string

Tags: java, json

What I want to achieve is to check if all the values of a JSON object is of type String. I have read about JSONObject's `getString` method and thought about making a while-loop that iterates through a JSON object, but I think this will be an inefficient solution to the problem.

Is there a library that can achieve value-type checking for all values of a JSON object? (ex. all JSON values are String, Integer, boolean, etc.)

Any advice/tip is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already? Typically on this site code is diagnosed not created at a whim based on proposed ideological constraints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = keys.next();
    if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof String) {
          // do something with jsonObject here      
    }
}
```